# Using c89 in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, c89

Is there any way to compile C code with c89 standard **NOT** c99 in Xcode (or another way with terminal)?

I've searched in Xcode settings but I didn't find any way to choose compiler or standard.

Comment: Referencing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291202/how-to-add-two-compiler-flags-in-xcode), you could add the compiler flag `-std=c89.`

Comment: Search again. Select your project, then in the right pane, select Build Settings, underneath that select All/Combined, and then in the search box type `C language`. The language dialect options will be there to choose from, and c89 is among them.

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn't work. for example, I used initialisation in for loop like this:
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
}
and it didn't show any problem - it worked successfully without anything wrong,

Comment: It will probably end up being a bug in Apple's clang, because I just tried it from the command line sans-Xcode, just for the hell of it. Even going back to `-ansi`, much less `-std=c89`, loop-var-declarations still pass. Dunno what the problem is, maybe someone already filed a bug with Apple. Bummer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `-pedantic-errors` to **Other C flags** in your project settings, like so:

[image: Solution]

Of course, don't forget to set the **C language dialect** to **C89** as well.

This will give you the appropriate compile time errors when you try to compile something that is not valid C89.

Optionally, if you want Xcode to compile your code regardless of incompatibilities, but only give you yellow warnings at the problematic lines, use `-pedantic` instead of `-pedantic-errors`.

In a nutshell, these flags make the compiler stick to the language standard more strictly, as opposed to the default behavior, which is to attempt compiling the code any way possible.

I hope this helps :)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493621/3606363)
(even though they mention this in the context of GCC, but the same flags apply for Clang as well)